# Is it possible to apply dynamic style as string in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, styles

I have a `<span>` that I want to apply dynamic style to.

Style is stored in a css-like `string` variable and can be arbitrary e.g.

`myStyle = 'color: white; font-weight: bold;'`

or

`myStyle = 'background-color: red;'`

I expected it to work like

`<span style="{{myStyle}}">`

but it didn't.

I tried different options but none seem to work for me for different reasons:

- I can't put styles in a .css file and use class names because style is coming from server in the form of aforementioned string
- Using `[style.color]` etc. doesn't suit me because I don't know what the style can be
- Using `[ngStyle]` doesn't suit me because it expects object like `{'color': 'red', 'font-weight': 'bold'}` and I only have string

The reason I have a style stored in a string is because I need to apply it in HTML generated on the server where I simply pass that string to a placeholder variable in a velocity template.

I am almost confident that it can't be done the way I want but probably I am overlooking some solution.

Comment: did you also try `<span [style]="myStyle">`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It renders to a plain `<span>` without `style` attribute

Comment: seems a little strange, have you tried using a ViewChild to get the span and apply the styles via the ts?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. What's 'ts'? Typescript?

Comment: yeah, ts is short for typescript, its the file extension for typescript files as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is `DomSanitizer` and `bypassSecurityTrustStyle`

> Component side :

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private doms : DomSanitizer) {}

newStyle = 'background-color:red';

safeCss(style) {
    return this.doms.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
}
```

> Template side :

```
<p [style]="safeCss(this.newStyle)">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-style-string-sanitizer)**

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: restyled answer from @hiper2d ?

Comment: @user1767316 , nothing is restyled I was creating the demo at the same time , `bypassSecurityTrustStyle` is the solution , and I have provided the better solution. That's why OP accepted my answer. you can't judge directly by just comparing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Angular provides the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) service which can convert strings into style objects. I think this is exactly your case.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

sanitizeStyle() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('background-color: red');
}

<span [style]="sanitizeStyle()">
```

Comment: This should work, but this doesn't suit my needs for the reasons described in the question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Try my another solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think I will go the way of converting the incoming css string into a style object and then applying it to `<span>` using `[ngStyle]`